# NSWebView override VoiceOver when selected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `NSWebView` and when I use VoiceOver on `Mac OS X` it announces the `NSWebView` selection as "`HTML` content"  This is most likely going to confuse the end user as I am using it for a custom control and I have handled all the other accessibility aspects of the `NSWebView` correctly.

How can I override what VoiceOver announces for the `NSWebView`?  I have tried the following however it doesn't make any difference:

```
[webView accessibilitySetOverrideValue:@"Map View" forAttribute:NSAccessibilityDescriptionAttribute];
```

I have also tried `NSAccessibilityRoleDescriptionAttribute` and `NSAccessibilityTitleAttribute` for the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to subclass `NSWebView` and override `NSAccessibilityRoleDescriptionAttribute` in the `- (id)accessibilityAttributeValue:(NSString *)attribute` method:

```
- (id)accessibilityAttributeValue:(NSString *)attribute
{
    id value = nil;

    if ( [attribute isEqualToString:NSAccessibilityRoleDescriptionAttribute] )
    {
        value = @"Map View";
    }
    // all your other ifs here
    else
    {
        value = [super accessibilityAttributeValue:attribute];
    }

    return value;
}
```

Be sure that you're telling `NSAccessibility` what you're providing (specifically the `NSAccessibilityRoleDescriptionAttribute` part):

```
- (NSArray *)accessibilityAttributeNames
{
    static NSMutableArray *attributes = nil;

    if ( attributes == nil )
    {
        attributes = [[super accessibilityAttributeNames] mutableCopy];

        NSArray *additionalAttributes = @[NSAccessibilityDescriptionAttribute, NSAccessibilityRoleAttribute, NSAccessibilityChildrenAttribute, NSAccessibilityTitleUIElementAttribute, NSAccessibilityRoleDescriptionAttribute];

        for ( NSString *attribute in additionalAttributes )
        {
            if ( ![attributes containsObject:attribute] )
            {
                [attributes addObject:attribute];
            }
        }
    }

    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and if I break point on the if statement the attribute is only ever set to AXParent or AXChildren.  Any ideas?

Comment: See my edit. You might need to tell the protocol that you're providing `NSAccessibilityRoleDescriptionAttribute`.

Comment: I just tried doing that and when I breakpoint [attributes addObject:attribute]; on breaks twice for AXDescription and AXTitleUIElement but not for the others.  Also when using the Accesibility Inspector the AXRoleDescription is still showing 'HTML Content'  Is seems that AXRoleDescription is already part of [super accessibilityAttributeNames].  Any other ideas?